# Applying two-variable model to several groups

Tags: r

I have data which is listed with each stock's daily return directly after the other, like the following:

| Stock | Date | Return stock | Return market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stock 1 | March 1 | 1% | 2% |
| Stock 1 | March 2 | 0.5% | 1% |
| Stock 1 | March 3 | 3% | 0.7% |
| Stock 2 | March 1 | 5% | 2% |
| Stock 2 | March 2 | 3% | 1% |
| Stock 2 | March 3 | 4% | 0.7% |
| Stock 3 | March 1 | -1% | 2% |
| Stock 3 | March 2 | 0.2% | 1% |
| Stock 3 | March 3 | 6% | 0.7% |

It contains 2000 stocks and many more days than three, but this is a simplified version.

I want to apply the model "MarketModel", which takes one variable as stock returns and one as market return. This is to be done on each stock in the data frame. So first it applies the model on stock 1, then it continuous down the list to stock 2 and all the way to the end.
More info on model can be found here, but it is very simple:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eventstudies/versions/1.2.2/topics/marketModel

I then want to put the result into another data frame which lists different variables for each stock.

| Stock | Other variables | Result from model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stock 1 | Other values | Result for stock 1 |
| Stock 2 | ... | Result for stock 2 |
| Stock 3 | ... | Result for stock 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Stock 2000 | ... | ... |

I am a beginner at R and would be extremely thankful to anyone who could help me with this!

Comment: It would be much better if you put an example of the data. Use the `dput` function to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` function and `split` function.

The `split` function wil help you to list your data by stock, like this:

```
l <- split(data, data$Stock)
```

Now `l` is a list of data frames. Then, you can apply the model you want to all df with `lapply`, like this:

```
m <- lapply(l,modelfunction, formula=return_market~return_stock)
```

Now `m` is a list of models by stock.